# Is there a limitation on the number of files in an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, app-store

Is there a limitation on the number of files in an iphone app?
My app will contain about 2000 or more text files.Would i  be in trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Apple App Store Review Guidelines](http://stadium.weblogsinc.com/engadget/files/app-store-guidelines.pdf) do not mention anything about a limit to the number of files an app can have.

The only section refering to size limits is section 2.15

> Apps larger than 20MB in size will not
>   download over cellular networks (this
>   is automatically  prohibited by the
>   App Store)

Answer (score 2):

No, you should be fine, 2000 files isn't that many (more than usual but still not extreme)

The limit is probably the same limit as the directory structure can hold which is probably much much higher.

And even if you do hit that number, you can use subdirectories to hold your files.

NB If the files are all small they will be stored inefficiently - you might want to look into combining them into one file or using a simple database to store the data.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a limit on the number of files you can include in your app, but including thousands of files does slow down app installation a lot.

Going with a database is one solution.  Another option is putting your thousands of files into a .zip archive that you uncompress upon first run.